# my application.properties from dependency is not available in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, dependency-properties

I have spring boot application.
In this spring boot (fat-jar) application I have `classpath:config/application.properties` and `classpath:application-env.properties`.

I am starting this application using command:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=env -jar application.jar --some-parameter=some-value
```

**Question:** Why **`application.properties`** file is not available during initialization this application from classes (beans) localized in my dependency?

This file (**`application.properties`**) is localized in `classpath:application.properties` of my dependency.

I am expecting some properties with some specific prefix - using annotation:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "someprefix")
```

---

and again the same in other words:

Application **`A`** have `classpath:config/application.properties`
+ Application **`A`** have/is using dependency to some artifact **`D`**
dependency (jar) **`D.jar`** have **`classpath:application.properties`**
this application.properies is not available during initialization of bean **`B`** with annotatin `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "someprefix")`

---

according to [24.3 Application property files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)  "The classpath root" should be fine - but it is not.

This is fat-jar application - in one big jar we have everything - including folder `'lib'` with all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

OK, :(
solution of my issue was trivial. My application was loading different `classpath:/application.properites` than I thought.

I had another dependency jar introduced to my project not-directly (it was dependency for my dependency) which contains different `classpath:/application.properites`.

In other words everything works fine but **only one** 'classpath:/application.properties' is loaded even you have two in two different dependencies.

I used [/actuator/env](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) to find out which `classpath:/application.dependency` was loaded.

Comment: What is the solution though? How can you make both file to load?